# Maven dependency tree versus versioneye plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have question about a maven dependency list goal versus this plugin
https://github.com/versioneye/versioneye_maven_plugin
What is difference? Can anyone explain?

Does it show real results or maybe better choice is a using a maven dependency list goal? I would to know which dependencies with its versions will be finally used by my application.

Answer (score 0):

versionEye seems to have gone out of business. I have never heard of their plugin and would not recommend it.

The versions Maven plugin is the "official" plugin for constructing your `dependency:tree` or your `dependency:list`.

Comment: But does it provide real results?
I mean when library A and library B use the same library C but in different versions?

Comment: You certainly see if A and B use different versions of C.

Comment: If you want to see which versions finally "make it" into your application, use `dependency:list`.

Comment: I think you are wrong. https://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/maven-dependencytree-vs-dependencylist/  Dont forget about shade plugin

Comment: About what? Can you explain what you mean or give me an example?

Comment: @K2milJ33 I cannot follow you. What exactly do you doubt about my explanation? And what does this have to do with the Maven shade plugin?

Comment: BTW, the article you cite is 11 years old (so probably about a very old Maven version) and furthermore I do not see how it contradicts what I say.

Comment: I compared a depdency list result with a target  folder after clean build command. Folder contains two additional jars...

Comment: Another case is obvious: I can additionally add a file from the network resource to the resulting package and my War will be contain additional jar which can use 100 libraries not specified in a pom.xml... Do you understand now :)

Comment: I still cannot really follow you. To your first problem: Are you building a war? Does this war contain dependencies that are not in the `dependency:list`? This is often the result of not using `clean`. If you do `clean package`, the war will contain exactly what is in the `dependency:list`. For your second problem: I do not understand what you mean by "network resource". Dependencies are purely added through the POM, not through resources.

Comment: The first problem could also be the result of mixing dependencies in the POM with IDE-based dependencies (like adding libraries in Eclipse directly to the project). This should be avoided.

Comment: I can use my custom resource                                                                                     <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>lib/*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

Comment: So I am not sure that depdency list always show the same number of libraries from targe directory...

Comment: You should never use resources to add jars to your project. Always use the POM.

Comment: Ok, but imagine that I develop a tool which scan specified folders to provide information about libraries and licenses in particular project. I want to support Maven, SBT, Gradle, Nuget, etc.. So it is not depdendent on me....

Comment: Maybe better choice will be execute command like clean package or build from Gradle and scan some directory, 
But then I lose information about the relationships between libraries ...

Comment: Supporting non-Maven builds is a completely different story. In Maven, you never add libraries as resources.

Comment: Non maven builds? Can You explain? Some tips?

Comment: I cannot really help you with your Gradle, SBT or nuget builds.